# Qt foreach() only iterates once, ignoring the rest of the items

Tags: foreach, qt4

I'm trying to add some features to an older Qt4 application, and I'm new to Qt.  The application uses the `foreach` keyword which I believe is [implemented by Qt](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword).  However all `foreach` loops in the application only run once, regardless of the number of items that are in the container.

I added this sanity check to the application:

```
QString test("1234");

int i = 0;
foreach (QChar c, test) {
    i++;
}

int stl = 0;
for (QString::iterator j = test.begin(); j != test.end(); j++) {
    stl++;
}

qDebug()
    << "string:" << test
    << "size:" << test.size()
    << "foreach:" << i
    << "stl:" << stl
;
```

It always shows this message:

```
string: "1234" size: 4 foreach: 1 stl: 4
```

I've tested it with the above `QString` and with a `QModelIndexList` and each time it only runs the loop once, even when the container reports having more than one item, and in both cases the STL-style loop works fine, it's only the `foreach` that exits the loop early.

What am I doing wrong?  The application is built against Qt 4.8.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, it turns out this is a change in behaviour with GCC 9 ([bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90617)) to do with where `break;` statements should appear and what they do.

It seems GCC versions before 9 did the wrong thing, but Qt 4 was written around that behaviour, so once it was fixed in GCC 9, Qt's foreach looping broke.

It [looks like it has been addressed](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/c35a3f519007af44c3b364b9af86f6a336f6411b) in recent Qt versions but not unfortunately in Qt 4.